# FIS with k-fold cross validation?

Tags: cross-validation, matlab, fuzzy

I want to measure the fuzzy system performances directly through cross-validation. How can I do this? How the concept of training to get model and test the model?

Comment: Hi Wiga maulqi! Welcome to CV. Your question will be far more likely to receive a helpful answer if you (a) indicate what FIS means, (b) indicate how you are measuring "FIS performance," (c) describe the statistical model you are trying to cross-validate, and (d) try to rewrite your last sentence, as it's meaning is unclear in English. As it stands, I fear your questions will be closed as being too unclear. Best!

Comment: I'm sorry.. FIS is fuzzy inference system, and i want get the performance like accuracy. how the concept of training and test data using 10-fold cross validation in fuzzy? data is the data of patients who suffer from coronary heart disease from hospital

Comment: So Wiga maulqi, if you click the "edit" link in the lower left of your question, you will be able to edit it to improve along the lines I requested.